# JQuery Selector Re-Write

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I do this kind of thing all over the place, and I am looking for the most efficient (both computationally + syntactically) way to execute:

```
ids =[]
$('tr.selectON td').each( function() { 
    var answer_query = $(this).attr('id');
    if ( answer_query !== undefined ) { 
        ids.push( answer_query ) 
    }   
});
```

I have access to underscore.js, which I suspect will help.

Comment: `if ( this.id ) ids.push(this.id)` should catch most cases,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ids = $("tr.selectON td[id]").map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

Documentations :

**To get elements with `id` attribute** http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

**To filter id attribute** http://api.jquery.com/map/

**To convert result into array** http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: And now with explanation, please - where does the array or collection end up?

Comment: Touche, forgot to use `[id]`. ;-)

Comment: @Roozbeh, not exactly as it returns a jQuery object and not an array.

Comment: the result without get is not array..its jquery object..which has some properties of array..see my ques on SO about this here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158102/javascript-methods-that-can-not-be-called-from-jquery-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler, cant speak to the JQuery performance though:

```
ids =[]
$('tr.selectON td[id^=""]').each( function() { 
        ids.push( this.id ) 
});
```

"this" in the function is already a dom object, so you have direct access to its id.