# How does jQuery invoke methods of objects when an Array of jQuery objects is returned?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After passing a string "selector" into the jQuery function:

```
$('#onenode')
```

An array of jQuery object's is returned.

One of the methods of these object's is "html", which is why:

```
$('#onenode').html('hello!');
```

Works.

However...

This:

```
$('.somenodes')
```

Returns an array of jQuery objects, each of the objects in this array has the method "html".

So how does:

```
$('.somenodes').html('hello');
```

Work? The "html" method must be a method of the Array Object that is returned.

I assume therefore that the "html" method of the Array Object looks similar to this:

```
html: function(value) {
   for(var i=0; i<this.length; i+=1) {
      this[i].html(value);
   }
}
```

These are all assumptions, I'm pretty much guessing.

**I am attempting to create my own small library that uses "selectors", but I am struggling with this part. I know that this is probably incorrect -- could someone explain how jQuery really does it?**

Comment: Both selectors return a single jQuery object.

Comment: Instead of *guessing* why not just open sources and check?

Comment: You can look at the development source code of jQuery. It is very well commented and easy to read: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: or use this jQuery source viewer! http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.html

Comment: Actually, just have a look at it on github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L196

Comment: TaylorMac, you're starting off on the wrong foot. "An array of jQuery object's is returned" is an incorrect statement. A *single* jQuery object is returned, comprising a collection of DOM nodes determined by the selector passed to jQuery(), plus a whole raft of methods that can act on that collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is basically a big `prototype` with a bunch of methods that `return this`, where `this` is the instance of jQuery you're working with.

> I am attempting to create my own small library that uses "selectors"

Here's a very reduced example of a jQuery-like pattern that works in modern browsers:

```
(function(win, doc) {

  var __slice = [].slice;

  function jQuery(selector) {
    this.el = this._init(selector);
    this.length = this.el.length;
  }

  function $(selector) {
    return new jQuery(selector);
  }

  jQuery.prototype = {

    _init: function(selector) {
      return __slice.call(doc.querySelectorAll(selector));
    },

    each: function(fn) {
      return this.el.some(fn), this;
    },

    map: function(fn) {
      return this.el.map(fn), this;
    }

  };

  win.$ = $;

}(window, document));
```

You can use that to build your jQuery like library. It works exactly like jQuery:

```
$('p').each(function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

A currying function, `each` and `map` is all you need to get started. Those are the methods the jQuery uses pretty much everywhere to manipulate DOM elements. `this.el` is the array of elements while `this` is the jQuery instance. Just don't forget that you need to `return this` in every method that will be chained.

Comment: This is great. This makes sense to me, thank you for writing it to help me understand

Answer (score 1):

`$('.somenodes')` does not return an array, its a jquery object only, which have some functions of native array..

I also had similar doubt some time back, check this answer on my question..https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158649/1114536

jQuery objects currently support 3 array methods:

```
var methods = 'pop push reverse shift sort splice unshift concat join slice toString indexOf lastIndexOf filter forEach every map some reduce reduceRight'.split(' ')
var implemented = $.grep(methods, function(m) {
    return $.prototype[m] == Array.prototype[m];
});
console.log(implemented); // => ["push", "sort", "splice"]
```

They also have slice, but it's not the same slice as arrays have:

```
$.prototype.slice === Array.prototype.slice // => false
```