# jQuery library design: how does jQuery work like an array, yet it is an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given that you can access a jQuery object's members using array-like bracket syntax: `$myjQueryObject[0]`, it seems like jQuery extends the built-in `Array` object.  However, I can't seem to find where they do this, in the `jquery.js` file.

I've successfully accomplished something similar by extending the `Array` 'class', just curious how jQuery does it!

Comment: [You can't really subclass Array.](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) JQuery doesn't do it either - it just fakes the "length" property.

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457928/how-does-jquery-invoke-methods-of-objects-when-an-array-of-jquery-objects-is-ret?rq=1 lemme read this before anyone answers

Comment: What about the bracket syntax?  Does it just create numeric indexes?

Comment: The bracket syntax is just part of the language, and yes it uses numeric property names. (All property names, even in arrays, are technically strings anyway.)

Comment: I made an object with the `Array` as a prototype that seemed to work, but I didn't thoroughly test it.  I'm curious to read that link and see what's up, thanks!

Comment: There'll be quirks. It can be faked with using property getters and setters, but should be fully supported in ECMAScript 6.

Comment: Here's another dupe that's only now showing up in related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483445/how-do-jquery-objects-imitate-arrays?rq=1

Comment: @MikeLewis the main things that's hard is keeping the "length" property correctly set to match the numeric property names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any object can access its properties via `[]` notation.

```
var obj = {};

obj["foo"] = "bar";
obj[1]=  "baz";
```

In JavaScript, an Array is just a specialized object, so its `[]` syntax is the same as any other object.

In addition, the `Array.prototype` methods are generic by specification. They can be applied to any "array-like" object, meaning any object that has a numeric `.length` and numeric indices.

```
var obj = {"1": "bar", "0": "foo", "2": "baz"};

var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(obj, 1);

console.log(arr); // ["bar", "baz"]
```

Comment: And jQuery automatically maps all members to numeric indexes?

Comment: @MikeLewis: Correct. In addition, the native Array methods can be used on any object that has a numeric `.length` property and numeric indices.

Comment: The result here is incorrect. in my console it returns `[]` youll need to add `length` prop in order for it to work ( chrome)